# how to pass auth token in firebase database() 'on' method to access database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have set my firebase database rules to `"auth != null"` and to access the database through http request I can pass the auth Token with the api endpoint url like `http.get('url?auth=<auth-token>')`. But I want to access the firebase database through firebase SDK.

```
    firebase.database().ref('users'+ userId).on('value',(snapShot)=>{
        this.setState({user: snapShot.val()});
    })
```

Here I am not getting any response because my database rule is set to `"auth != null"`. So how can I pass the auth detail in this request.

Comment: As far as I know only Firebase Cloud Functions using Admin SDK can by pass the Firebase Database rules.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [sign in the user with Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) into your React app. Once you do so, the token will automatically be passed to the Realtime Database by the Firebase Authentication SDK.